# ¿Cómo puedo ajustar la herramienta lápiz y la rejilla de la imagen en Gimp?

Tags: gimp

Necesitaría que la rejilla de la imagén y mi lápiz encajaran a la perfección para poder hacer pixel art con el lápiz, intuyo que la configuración de la rejilla está mal o los parámetros de la herramienta lápiz están mal pero el caso es que tienen el mismo tamaño de 4 píxeles. Necesitaría crear un pincel de 4 x 4 en lugar de 3 x 3 que es el que tengo ahora pero no sé crearlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no parece versar sobre programación y eso sin duda generará el cierre de la misma

Comment: Trata sobre Gimp y está correctamente etiquetada.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no parece versar sobre una duda de programación.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la brocha que se llama Pixel, en realidad no tiene 1px de dimensión, si no 3x3 por lo que no va a ser exacto el escalado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una forma de resolverlo fácil es creando esa brocha.
Crea un Nuevo Documento de (1x1)px, lo pintas de negro y le das en Archivo - Exportar... con el nombre_que_quieras.gbr (en mi caso OnePixel.gbr)

Luego copias ese archivo en el directorio de usuario de Gimp, en el caso de **Windows**:

```
C:\Users\Tu_Usuario\AppData\Roaming\GIMP\2.10\brushes
```

Refrescas las brochas en el icono respectivo, o bien cierra el Gimp y vuelvelo a abrir.

Selecciona la nueva brocha con la herramienta de lápiz y listo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es una opción, pero la forma con la que lo conseguí solucionar fue creando un lápiz de 1x1,  es decir, ajustando el tamaño del lápiz y el de la imagen por que no tiene sentido estar pintando simpre en 3x3 ni en 4x4.